# Amarok 2.8 High Memory Usage in Kubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, memory-usage, amarok

On a brand new install of Kubuntu 16.04 I have noticed that Amarok is the biggest memory hog right from the start with 450Mb.

The same Amarok version on Kubuntu 14.04 uses only 75Mb.

Any hints or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Edit 1:

I looked at the detailed memory usage of Amarok in Kubuntu 16.04 and 14.04 and pasted a small portion of each below. Each process invoked seems to be 2~3 times larger in 16.04 than in 14.04.

In 16.04 I have:

```
439424 KB   [heap]
16052 KB    /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_collection-mysqlecollection.so
12456 KB    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4.10.2
7792 KB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_gui.so.1.0.0
4836 KB /usr/lib/libamaroklib.so.1.0.0
3104 KB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.7
2504 KB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_core.so.1.0.0
2128 KB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtScript.so.4.8.7
1936 KB /usr/lib/libplasma.so.3.0.0
956 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_network.so.1.0.0
872 KB  /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5.14.16
832 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.801.0
632 KB  /usr/lib/libamarok-sqlcollection.so.1.0.0
560 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtag.so.1.14.0
560 KB  /usr/lib/libamarokcore.so.1.0.0
544 KB  /usr/lib/libkfile.so.4.14.16
488 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_xml.so.1.0.0
488 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtOpenGL.so.4.8.7
448 KB  /var/tmp/kdecache-dell/plasma_theme_default_v2.0.kcache
444 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libphonon.so.4.8.3
360 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstplayback.so
348 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/phonon_backend/phonon_gstreamer.so
344 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/plugins/script/libkrossqtsplugin.so.4.14.16
336 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0.801.0
332 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcoreelements.so
324 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_uitools.so.1.0.0
304 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libibus-qt.so.1.3.0
300 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_service_magnatunestore.so
284 KB  /usr/lib/libkio.so.5.14.16
280 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.8.7
256 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstvideo-1.0.so.0.801.0
244 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_dri.so
244 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstvideo4linux2.so
240 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_service_amazonstore.so
232 KB  /usr/lib/libamarokshared.so.1.0.0
224 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/bearer/libqconnmanbearer.so
216 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_sql.so.1.0.0
208 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_collection-umscollection.so
204 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_collection-ipodcollection.so
204 KB  /[aio] (deleted)
204 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0.801.0
```

In 14.04 I have:

```
32020 KB    [heap]
5512 KB /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_collection-mysqlecollection.so
3112 KB /usr/lib/libamaroklib.so.1.0.0
2640 KB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_gui.so.1.0.0
2048 KB [stack:2875]
2048 KB [stack:2867]
1676 KB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtWebKit.so.4.10.2
1608 KB /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_core.so.1.0.0
616 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0.204.0
464 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtGui.so.4.8.6
432 KB  /usr/lib/libamarok-sqlcollection.so.1.0.0
312 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_xml.so.1.0.0
296 KB  /usr/lib/libamarokcore.so.1.0.0
284 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_network.so.1.0.0
252 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/phonon_backend/phonon_gstreamer.so
248 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtXmlPatterns.so.4.8.6
228 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libphonon.so.4.7.80
216 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_uitools.so.1.0.0
196 KB  /usr/lib/libkdeui.so.5.13.3
164 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstplayback.so
160 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstcoreelements.so
156 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmtp.so.9.1.0
148 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libQtDeclarative.so.4.8.6
140 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/plugins/script/libqtscript_sql.so.1.0.0
132 KB  /usr/lib/libplasma.so.3.0.0
128 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_collection-ipodcollection.so
120 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liborc-0.4.so.0.18.0
116 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_context_applet_currenttrack.so
116 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.10
116 KB  /usr/lib/libkio.so.5.13.3
108 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_collection-umscollection.so
108 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0.204.0
104 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_context_applet_wikipedia.so
104 KB  /usr/lib/kde4/amarok_context_applet_lyrics.so
100 KB  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgstaudio-1.0.so.0.204.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Memory usage in Amarok can be decreased by changing the phonon backend from gstreamer to phonon-backend-vlc. Run the following:

```
sudo apt-get install amarok phonon-backend-vlc
```

Then open Amarok and follow this trail:

```
Settings > Configure Amarok > Playback > Configure Phonon > Backend
```

And when you are there select vlc, as demonstrated in the screenshot below:

[image]

As you can see you now have the option of switching from one backend to the other; useful if you wish to generate some hard statistics of memory usage with the different backends....

**References:**

- [Kde Forums: Amarok 2.8.0 Memory Issues](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=115&t=118690)

Comment: No change in the amount of ram used, still at 450Mb